# Referencing a part of regular expression code elsewhere

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a regular expression like so

```
preg_match_all('@(1[0-9]+) (1[0-9]+)@'...
```

If unleashed on the following string:

```
Speed 1000 11234
Weight 1324 1456
```

It returns two matches
1000 11234
and
1324 1456

Is there any way to back-reference the regex code in the first parentheses later in the regex?

For example:

```
preg_match_all('@(1[0-9]+) (\backRef1)@'... // This pseudocode is identical to @(1[0-9]+) (1[0-9]+)@
```

I am not looking for match reference *\1*, because that only works for mirror matches like 123 123

I also do not want to save the regex string into a variable and then paste it inside like `"@($pattern) ($pattern)@"` I want to reference it directly within the regex itself.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. The actual regexes I want it for have patterns miles and miles long and repeat several times inside of the regex, so it makes the regex much longer plus if I want to change something in the pattern I have to change it several times in the other patterns as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Regular Expression Subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html).

You can reference the group one by eg `\g<1>` or `(?1)`

```
(1[0-9]+) (?1)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dRzb9w/4)

Update for use with *named capture group*:

```
(?<test>1[0-9]+) \g'test'
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dRzb9w/5/)

There is also the [`define`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html#define) syntax available.

Comment: Nearly perfect! Is it possible to reference the pattern by a name? For example (?P<test>1[0-9]+) (\b(?<test>)) ?

Comment: @Askerman Maybe such as [`(?P<test>[0-9]+) (\b\g'test')`](https://regex101.com/r/dRzb9w/3/)